# Sequelize order virtual fields

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need calculate popularity of works , this is calculated by number of likes +  views ,

Then I have relations like this:

```
User.belongsToMany(models.Work, {as: 'Likes', through: 'Likes'});
User.belongsToMany(models.Work, {as: 'Views', through: 'Views'});
```

I want when I find all works they be order by popularity , the popularity cannot be an column in the table , because this is calculated by  time , I think that this  should be a virtual field.

```
global.db.Work.findAll({order: '`popularity` DESC'}).then(function(works){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The logical solution would be creating a view in you database (if it is a sql database). Otherwise:
1. You have to make a raw query:

```
sequelize.query("SELECT *, work.likes + work.views AS popularity FROM work ORDER BY popularity DESC", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
.then(function(returnedRecords) {
    // do your staff
    // it's harder to manipulated returned records though if you want to
    // change records and save into db.
})
```

2. Order the results inside your script.